# Is $f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n a^k$ bijective in $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the values of $a$ for which the following function $f:\{0,1,\dots,m-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$ is bijective for a fixed $m$?
 $$f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n a^k$$

Comment: The formula is valid in any commutative ring, whether $\;a-1\;$ is a unit or whatever. We *only* need $\;a\neq 1\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio what does the formula mean if $a-1$ is not a unit???

Comment: Oh, I see now: division by $\;a-1\;$...right, it must be a unit. I was thinking of $\;a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)\;$ ...good point.

Comment: It's wrong to say that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb Z_m$: the values of $f(n)$ and $f(n+m)$ are different in general. Perhaps you mean that the domain is $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$?

Comment: Yes, I had not noticed that meaning. Thank you!

Comment: Trivial observation: (I'm not sure if you already noticed that)
$a$ necessarily has to be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m$, as otherwise $2$ is not contained in the image.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Louis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ works as a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) for which $c = 1$, as:

$$f(n+1) \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a^k \equiv a \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a^k\right) + 1 \equiv a f(n) + 1 \ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$$

If the equivalent LCG has a full period, then $f$ is bijective. If $f$ is bijective, $f(k) \ne 0 \ \ \forall k < m-1$ (if $f(k) = 0$, $f(k+1) = 1 = f(0)$ and $f$ is not bijective), thus $f(m-1) = 0$ and the next value for the LCG will be equal to the seed $1$, so the LCG has a full period for any possible seed.

Therefore $f$ is bijective if and only if:

1. $a-1$ is multiple of every prime dividing $m$.
2. $m$ is not multiple of $4$ or $a-1$ is multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer, but some data: it's always bijective for $a=1$. For some composite moduli, there are arithmetic progressions of $a$ for which it's bijective. For example, when $m=9$, it's bijective for $a=1,4,7$.

In general, there exist moduli $m$ and divisors $d$ of $m$ for which it's bijective precisely when $a\equiv 1\pmod d$. The list for $m\le100$ is:

- $m=8$, $d=4$
- $m=9$, $d=3$
- $m=16$, $d=4$
- $m=18$, $d=6$
- $m=24$, $d=12$
- $m=25$, $d=5$
- $m=27$, $d=3$
- $m=32$, $d=4$
- $m=36$, $d=12$
- $m=40$, $d=20$
- $m=45$, $d=15$
- $m=48$, $d=12$
- $m=49$, $d=7$
- $m=50$, $d=10$
- $m=54$, $d=6$
- $m=56$, $d=28$
- $m=63$, $d=21$
- $m=64$, $d=4$
- $m=72$, $d=12$
- $m=75$, $d=15$
- $m=80$, $d=20$
- $m=81$, $d=3$
- $m=88$, $d=44$
- $m=90$, $d=30$
- $m=96$, $d=12$
- $m=98$, $d=14$
- $m=99$, $d=33$
- $m=100$, $d=20$

Observations: the moduli $m$ are precisely the integers whose greatest square factor exceeds $4$. The divisors $d$ always have all prime factors of the corresponding $m$; in fact, $d$ is the largest squarefree divisor of $m$ when $m$ isn't a multiple of $4$, and twice the largest squarefree divisor of $m$ when $m$ is a multiple of $4$.